# access value of a python dict() without knowing the keys

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary of a list of dictionaries. something like below:

`x = {'a':[{'p':1, 'q':2}, {'p':4, 'q':5}], 'b':[{'p':6, 'q':1}, {'p':10, 'q':12}]}`

The length of the lists (values) is the same for all keys of dict x.
I want to get the length of any one value i.e. a list without having to go through the obvious method -> get the keys, use len(x[keys[0]]) to get the length.

my code for this as of now:

```
val = None
for key in x.keys():
    val = x[key]
    break
    #break after the first iteration as the length of the lists is the same for any key
try:
    what_i_Want = len(val)
except TypeError:
    print 'val wasn't set'
```

i am not happy with this, can be made more 'pythonic' i believe.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: I just want the length of any list viz. the value of any key. All values have the same length

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about this:

```
val = x[x.keys()[0]]
```

or alternatively:

```
val = x.values()[0]
```

and then your answer is

```
len(val)
```

---

Some of the other solutions (posted by thefourtheye and gnibbler) are better because they are not creating an intermediate list. I added this response merely as an easy to remember and obvious option, not a solution for time-efficient usage.

Comment: @JoranBeasley Nice option, added to answer.

Comment: Mind. this one doesn't work in Python3, and it does create a temporary list of all the values.

Comment: @jeev But, this is exactly what you did *NOT* want, as per your question. `without having to go through the obvious method -> get the keys, use len(x[keys[0]]) to get the length`

Comment: @thefourtheye , I accepted the answer cuz I didn't know that one could just exec a x.values() to get a list of all values (am a python newbie, go easy on me!) .

Comment: @gnibbler I will need the list of values for other purposes later in my code , I am using python 2.7 .

Comment: @jeev No problem :) I am just trying to point out that [mine](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21820448/1903116) and [gnibbler's second solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21820470/1903116) are far better than this solution, since we don't create intermediate list. :)

Comment: Yes @thefourtheye I see that, really compact. you 2 get an upvote for that!

Answer (score 5):

This is most efficient way, since we don't create any intermediate lists.

```
print len(x[next(iter(x))])   # 2
```

**Note:** For this method to work, the dictionary should have atleast one key in it.

Answer (score 4):

Works ok in Python2 or Python3

```
>>> x = {'a':[{'p':1, 'q':2}, {'p':4, 'q':5}], 'b':[{'p':6, 'q':1}, {'p':10, 'q':12}]}
>>> next(len(i) for i in x.values())
2
```

This is better for Python2 as it avoids making a list of the values. Works well in Python3 too

```
>>> next(len(x[k]) for k in x)
2
```

Answer (score 2):

Using [`next`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next) and [`iter`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#iter):

```
>>> x = {'a':[{'p':1, 'q':2}, {'p':4, 'q':5}], 'b':[{'p':6, 'q':1}, {'p':10, 'q':12}]}
>>> val = next(iter(x.values()), None) # Use `itervalues` in Python 2.x
>>> val
[{'q': 2, 'p': 1}, {'q': 5, 'p': 4}]
>>> len(val)
2

>>> x = {}
>>> val = next(iter(x.values()), None) # `None`: default value
>>> val is None
True
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> x = {'a':[{'p':1, 'q':2}, {'p':4, 'q':5}], 'b':[{'p':6, 'q':1}, {'p':10, 'q':12}]}
>>> len(x.values()[0])
2
```

Here, x.values gives you a list of all values then you can get length of any one value from it.